# Critique reasoning

Tags: fractions

Molly is wrapping parts of sandwiches to sell at her sandwich cart . She cuts each sandwich in fourths and then wraps each fourth separately. She says that she wrapped 16 fourths, so she wrapped 16 hole sandwiches. What was Molly's mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Molly has done as she said, and has cut each sandwich into fourths, and has in fact wrapped 16 fourths separately:

She has then wrapped $\frac{16}{4} = 4$ whole sandwiches, not $16$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of sandwich.

If a sandwich consists of
two pieces of bread
with something in between them,
then cutting a sandwich into four parts
creates four smaller sandwiches.

With this definition,
Molly is correct.

If cutting a sandwich
into parts
does *not* create
multiple sandwiches
(you may need to come up
with a term for what these are),
then Molly is wrong.